# Viewport for pixelart (WebGL)

Tags: textures, webgl, resolution

I'm trying to display `16x16` pixel art textures (all textures have `16x16`), but they are not displayed how I expected (they are kind of blurry). I have seen this question before [question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/143498/best-base-resolution-for-a-pixelart-project-for-bigger-audience), but this was not answering my question.

My approach:

I use the `resize` from this url [webglfundamentals](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-resizing-the-canvas.html)

Which means my `canvas` has the following properties :

- `width:100vw`
- `height:100vh`

Then I set my `viewport` to:

- `gl.viewport(0,0,gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height)`

For the `sprite rendering` I use a `orthographic camera`:

- `function ortho(out, 0, gl.canvas.width, 0, gl.canvas.height, 0, 1)` (from [glmatrix](http://glmatrix.net/docs/mat4.js.html#line1323))

The sprite I'am trying to display consists of this vertices :

- `new Float32Array([-0.5, -0.5, 0.0, 0.5, -0.5, 0.0, -0.5, 0.5, 0.0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0]);`

which means it is very small, so I scaled them up.
I understand that my original texture has only the size `16x16` and when I scale it up it gets stretched. So my question is how would you setup the `viewport` and why? **(Also an explanation would be nice, since I have the feeling I did not quite understand the connection between `viewport`, `orthographic camera` and `width and height of the canvas`)**.

Comment: If you don´t get the parts don´t try the combo. For starters skip ortho completely and render directly into NDC space where -1 is bottom/left and 1 is top/right. Resize canvas and see what happens. Then make an ortho so that ratio is preserved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a problem with the canvas. The textures get blurry because of the max filter parameter. You can set it with the [texParameterf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/texParameter) function:

```
gl.texParameterf(texture, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST)
```

If you instead want to make the viewport smaller (the size of the display in pixels), then you need to use gl.viewport with the desired width and height of the canvas.