# Normalise movement for direction with 16:9 aspect

Tags: c++, mathematics, vector

should i move everything by the windows Normalised cords to make it so SE is bottom-right, or should i use (1,1) and move everything at or either (1+speedX,1+speedY)

```
d = (WindowOrigin*2).GetNormalise();
    v+=vec2f(0,-d.y);
```

or

```
d = (1,1).GetNormalise();
    v+=vec2f(0,-d.y);
```

reason i ask is because using the first one makes it feel like up and down move slower then left and right even though it takes same amount of time

i can post more code but i really dont think its gonna show anything useful
the image shows both options i can use
[image]

Comment: You may want to [decouple the world space coordinate system you use for processing your game simulation from the screen space coordinate system used for display](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/149857/39518). This makes it easier to guarantee consistent behaviour on any screen resolution or aspect ratio, without peppering adjustment constants throughout all your gameplay code.

Comment: I tried to understand it, when you say 0 to screen extent range do you mean between 0 and 1?

Comment: You can see that example is measured in pixels, so for eg. a 1920 by 1080 screen, on-screen pixel coordinates would be in the range \$x \in [0, 1920), y \in [0, 1080)\$, and the screen center vector would be \$(960, 540)\$. You don't need to use that math exactly - the idea is just to use one coordinate system for your gameplay, and map the visible sprites or other rendered content to a distinct coordinate system for display. Then you can change display behaviour any way you want, without needing to revisit or re-tune all your gameplay code.