# My pixel art looks weird in the game view in Unity

Tags: unity, textures, rendering, sprites

I am making my first 2D game in Unity and something has been bothering me. If I'm in the scene view, my game looks fine but when I go to the game view the pixels in the sprites aren't rendered correctly and everything looks distorted.

[image]
[image]

Does anyone know an answer to this?

Comment: Btw my pixel size is 16 by 16

Comment: You're not maintaining an integer pixel to texel ratio. See [some](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/131445/39518) past [answers](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/131461/39518) on this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35829604/3064164). The quickest fix is to use the Pixel Perfect Camera in Unity, if you don't want to calculate the ratios yourself.

Comment: @DMGregory Thanks! I used the Pixel Perfect Camera component and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You're not maintaining an integer pixel to texel ratio. See some past answers on this topic. The quickest fix is to use the Pixel Perfect Camera in Unity, if you don't want to calculate the ratios yourself. – DMGregory♦ (see comment)