# Downscaling from 1080 to 768 in Unity 2D

Tags: unity, camera, sprites, resolution

I have an orthographic camera of size = `10.8` and I use it as base and have developed the game for a `1080` display. On a `768` display, the sprites look blurry, or in other words, the quality is bad as the sprites are downscaled.

Currently, one of the most used sprite size in my game is `120 x 120`. The PPU is `100`, so the sprites of this size take up `1.2` units to render. To make it adapt to a 768 display, I did some calculations:

```
120 * 768 / 1080 = 85.33
```

Then, I rounded it off to the nearest integer that will give an integral value for the PPU too, which gave me `84`. The PPU in this case would be,

```
84 / 1.2 = 70 (keeping 1.2 as constant, so that the in-code calculations won't get affected)
```

And the new resolution turned out to be,

```
84 * 1080 / 120 = 756
```

with `(768 - 756) / 2 = 6px` of black stripes at the top and bottom. But, I got the same result. The sprites still looked blurry.

The second thing I tried was to change the orthographic size to `7.56` (from previous calculation) along with the sprites of new size that I duplicated using the previous calculation. In this case, the sprites looked sharp, but the base units of `1.2` (which is for most of the sprites) was changed and I had to update almost everything in the game, the calculations that depend upon it, size of the colliders, etc. which is a very big task also might incur some bugs.

I have found numerous articles / posts about upscaling but never have I found a post about downscaling. Is there a standard way to achieve sharp sprites even on lower resolutions?

Comment: Maybe you can use [mipmaps](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/texture-mipmaps-introduction.html). The mipmap sampling is determined by the texel size rather than the distance, so it's working in 2D also. This will somewhat reduce aliasing and artifacts, but at the end of the day it's hard to get the perfect sprite.

Comment: Your idea of changing the orthographic camera size was good. But you don't want to change PPU without changing the source image itself — otherwise you're changing the size and spacing of things in your game world, not just the zoom of the view into it. You may be interested in [Scaling my pixel art platformer from 720p to 1080p](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/131461/39518) — not quite the same situation, but many of the same considerations apply. To get a crisp down-sample, you want to scale images by powers of two, or swap them for alternate assets at the new resolution.