# How to scale UI for different screen resolutions

Tags: godot-4

Godot 4.2.1, *not* a pixel art game. This is about scaling the UI, not sprites etc. I am targeting 1080p (base resolution), 1440p, and 4K. 4K is easy, I just set the scale to 2. But for 1440p, if I set the scale to a fraction (say 1.33), the UI looks slightly blurry. I thought the magical "integer scaling" checkbox will solve it for me but it does not seem to make any difference (I may be misunderstanding its purpose though).

One idea is to have a separate theme for 1440p, with different font size, margins on UI elements etc., and switch the theme when the 1440p resolution is selected by the player (instead of changing the scale). Is this a good idea, and what would be the drawbacks (for example, is managing two themes a lot of pain)? Is there a better approach to avoid the blur?

Comment: A similar case is discussed in [Scaling my pixel art platformer from 720p to 1080p](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/131454/39518) — the same things that make the 720p → 1080p adjustment difficult also apply to 1080p → 1440p. Depending on your UI style though, other options may be available that don't work for pixel art. For example, if your UI is mostly crisp-edged single-colour vector-like shapes, representing them as signed distance fields can help get crisp scaling over a wider range of sizes. Can you show us a screenshot or representative sample of the kind of thing you want to scale?